# Redirect to subdomain then rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked at dozens of examples but I'm still having problems.  I'm trying to redirect and rewrite the following:

My long URL is:

```
http://old.domain.com/index.php?AssetID={long_guid_here}
```

I've successfully redirected to:

```
http://old.domain.com/{long_guid_here}
```

But now I need to redirect the whole thing to:

```
http://new.domain.com/index.php?AssetID={long_guid_here}
```

and make it look nice:

```
http://new.domain.com/{long_guid_here}
```

The following gets me the redirect but not the "nice" part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.domain.com/index.php?AssetID=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.domain.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Note : you will have to add an .htaccess file in the new.domain.com that rewrite from *nice* to *normal*

**Edit**

if you new.domain.com is pointed to the same directory as the old.domain.com (that meens same htaccess file), then add these lines too :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?AssetID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That's the problem, it's actually the same virtual host.  Both subdomains are there we are just calling it something else now.  I need the redirect and rewrite to happen sequentially.

Comment: If you are sending any other query string values to the PHP script, make sure you use the `QSA` flag.

Comment: That's giving me:  `http://old.domain.com/{long_guid_here}`, which isn't correct.  Remember, people aren't using the new domain name, even though it's a ServerAlias.

Comment: did you add all the 5lines ?
this should make the users redirected to the new domain THEN rewrited to the index file

Comment: You nailed it, sorry I didn't put both sets (all 5 lines together)!  Thank you!